# Angular - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngStyle' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular

In Angular-11, I have this code:

password-metre.component.ts:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-password-meter',
  templateUrl: './password-meter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./password-meter.component.css']
})
export class PasswordMeterComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() passwordString: string;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  get passwordStrength() {
    const password = this.passwordString || '';
    let score = Math.min(4, password.length / 2);
    if (/[a-z]/.test(password)) {
      score += 1;
    }

    if (/[a-z](.)*[a-z]/.test(password)) {
      score += 3;
    }
    if (/[A-Z]/.test(password)) {
      score += 1;
    }
    if (/[A-Z](.)*[A-Z]/.test(password)) {
      score += 2;
    }

    if (/\W|_/.test(password)) {
      score += 2;
    }

    if (/(\W|_)(.)*(\W|_)/.test(password)) {
      score += 3;
    }
    if (/[0-9]/.test(password)) {
      score += 2;
    }

    if (/[0-9](.)*[0-9]/.test(password)) {
      score += 2;
    }

    return (score / 20) * 100;
  }

  get colorString() {
    const hue = ((this.passwordStrength / 100) * 120).toString(10);
    return ['hsl(', hue, ',100%,50%)'].join('');
  } 
}
```

password-metre.component.html:

```html
<small>New Password Strength</small>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" [ngStyle]='{ backgroundColor: colorString }' role="progressbar" [style]='{width: passwordStrength + "%"}' aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    {{ passwordStrength | number:'2.0-0' }}%
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-secondary" role="progressbar" [ngStyle]='{ width: (100 - passwordStrength) + "%" }' aria-valuenow="15" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
  </div>
</div>
```

But I got this errors:

> Error: src/app/features/auth/pages/password-metre/password-metre.component.html:5:5 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngStyle' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

> 5     [ngStyle]='{ backgroundColor: colorString }'
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> m
> src/app/features/auth/pages/password-metre/password-metre.component.ts:5:16
> 5   templateUrl: './password-metre.component.html',
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Error occurs in the template of component PasswordMetreComponent.

> Error: src/app/features/auth/pages/password-metre/password-metre.component.html:9:27 - error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'number'.

> 9     {{ passwordStrength | number:'2.0-0' }}%                            ~~~~~~

> src/app/features/auth/pages/password-metre/password-metre.component.ts:5:16
> 5   templateUrl: './password-metre.component.html',
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Error occurs in the template of component PasswordMetreComponent.

These lines are highlighted:

> [ngStyle]='{ backgroundColor: colorString }'

> {{ passwordStrength | number:'2.0-0' }}%

> templateUrl: './password-metre.component.html',

What do I do to get it resolved?

Thanks

Comment: Does your feature module have `@angular/common` imported?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky - Yes. It's there:      import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

Comment: But is it also in `imports: [CommonModule]` of the `@NgModule()`?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky - Sorry, I dont understand. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

In your `@NgModule` where the `PasswordMeterComponent` is declared, you need to make sure that [CommonModule](https://angular.io/api/common) is included in `imports`:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PasswordMeterComponent } from './path/to/password-meter.component.ts';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [PasswordMeterComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule], // include CommonModule in 'imports'
  providers: [],
})
export class YourFeatureModule {}
```

Hopefully that helps!